# Set value for multiple variables at once?

Tags: initialization, ti-basic

While programming a sample program in my TI-84 calculator, I was wondering if there were a way to initialize multiple variables to a single value in one line?
I tried doing

```
0 -> A,B,C,D
```

However this did not work for the calculator. I know you can do each one on an individual line, but my question is, is it possible to initialize multiple variables to a single value at once in TI-BASIC?

Comment: My apologies, I removed this example from the question.

Answer (score 4):

**No.** You cannot initialize multiple variables to a single value at once in TI-Basic.

However, you can:

1. Set all values in an array or matrix to the same value at once.
2. Initialize variables to zero in three bytes instead of four using `DelVar (variable)` and then leaving off the following colon. For example, instead of doing `:0->A:0->B:Disp A,B` you can do `:DelVar ADelVar BDisp A,B`.
3. Remember that uninitialized variables are treated as zero when first used.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't set multiple variables at once with one value.  But if you just want them on the same line, you can use a colon like this `0→A:0→B`.  If you really feel like it, you could make another program that zeroes out every variable and just call it from within your program like this.

```
PROGRAM:ZERO
:0→A
:0→B
:0→C
...

PROGRAM:OTHER
:prgmZERO
...
```